# Nested template possibilities

Tags: c++, templates, nested

Is the following valid?:

```
template<typename T> class C { C1<C2<T>> someMember; };
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've taken from it what I can, but this is a pretty bad question. We have no idea what `C1` and `C2` are, we don't know what your real problem is, and what your goals are. No it's not valid because `C1` and `C2` aren't defined, or even if they were how I've defined them, now it's not valid because `>>` is the right shift operator. And if we introduce a space, it's not valid because you've merely named a type and not declared anything. Far too incomplete; provide real code, real problems, and real goals if you want real answers.

Comment: The answer you provided is real.

Comment: @drenami: Alright, just keep in mind I had to guess. :) The thing is, most people ask "is this valid" because they've encountered some sort of error. When you ask such a question with no error messages and incomplete code, it screams "there's more to this!" and we like having that more. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you'd need to do something with the type, either make it a typedef or member, but yes:

```
template <typename T>
struct C1 {};

template <typename T>
struct C2 {};

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    typedef C1<C2T> > type; // note the space!
};
```

`>>` is actually the right shift operator, so you need a space in there for it to work correctly. In C++0x, however, you can just type `>>`; it is parsed just fine.*

<sub>*Some lenient compilers will currently accept it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Erm, no, at least not in isolation, because you have no definition for `C1` and `C2`. Assuming that they are defined to be template classes with one argument, then no, it's still not valid for the same reason that `int;` is not valid -- it's not a complete statement, its just a typename.

Now if you're asking about the syntax with the angle-brackets, then ignoring all of the other issues, that is only valid in C++0x. In the current C++ standard, the parse is ambiguous, and you would have to form it as `C1<C2<T> >`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I've used:

```
vector< pair<int, int> > blah;
```

before.